# How can I improve this JSON-LD Schema for local service area business?

Tags: json, seo, schema, schema.org, json-ld

I am new to any kind of coding and put this together myself. I have a service area business... no brick and mortar store.. and we cover about a 30 mile radius of Sacramento, CA. This is the JSON-LD I have made for my home page.
I think I am supposed to make JSON-LD schema for other pages as well, but not sure what to put on it that is different than this?
I also feel like I am missing stuff that would really help me out in search results, but I am not sure what. I am open to all feedback!
website: www.yogabearpc.com
Here is my current home page code:

```
    <script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "ProfessionalService",
"address": {
"@type": "PostalAddress",
"addressLocality": "Sacramento",
"addressRegion": "CA",
"postalCode":"95816",
"streetAddress": ""
},
"description": "Yoga Bear Computer Repair is a mobile and onsite computer repair company in Sacramento, CA. Rated #1, we repair laptops, desktops, PCs, and Apple Macs.",
"name": "Yoga Bear Computer Repair",
"telephone": "916-800-3035",
"openingHours": "Mo-Su 00:00-24:00",
"geo": {
"@type": "GeoCoordinates",
"latitude": "38.56",
"longitude": "-121.47"
    }, 
"logo": "http://www.yogabearpc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/logo.jpg",
"email":"mailto:yogabearpc@gmail.com",
"url":"http://www.yogabearpc.com/",
"sameAs" : [ "https://www.facebook.com/yogabearpc",
"http://www.twitter.com/YogaBearPC",
"https://plus.google.com/+YogaBearPCRepairSacramento",
"https://www.instagram.com/yogabearpc/",
"https://www.linkedin.com/in/yoga-bear-computer-repair-178a32111",
"https://www.pinterest.com/yogabearpc/",
"https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHmmLsYH9252HxlOjXD9t9w",
"https://www.yelp.com/biz/yoga-bear-computer-repair-sacramento-2"]
}
```

Comment: I think this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, unless you have a specific problem/question. You seem to want a code review, which is on-topic on [codereview.se]. You could flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

Consider this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ProfessionalService",
    "name": "Yoga Bear Computer Repair",
    "description": "Yoga Bear Computer Repair is a mobile and onsite computer repair company in Sacramento, CA. Rated #1, we repair laptops, desktops, PCs, and Apple Macs.",
    "areaServed": [{
        "@type": "Place",
        "geo": {
            "@type": "GeoCircle",
            "geoMidpoint": {
                "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
                "latitude": "38.56",
                "longitude": "-121.47"
            },
            "geoRadius": "50"
        }
    },
    {
        "@type": "Place",
        "hasMap": "place URL to map here; e.g. the Google map URL"
    },
    {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressLocality": "Sacramento",
            "addressRegion": "CA",
            "postalCode": "95816"
        }
    }],
    "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "Sacramento",
        "addressRegion": "CA",
        "postalCode": "95816",
        "streetAddress": ""
    },
    "contactPoint": {
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "url": "http://www.yogabearpc.com/",
        "contactType": "customer service",
        "telephone": "+1.916.800.3035",
        "email": "yogabearpc@gmail.com",
        "hoursAvailable": {
            "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
            "dayOfWeek": ["Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday",
            "Sunday"],
            "opens": "08:00",
            "closes": "18:00"
        }
    },
    "logo": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "http://www.yogabearpc.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/logo.jpg",
        "width": {
            "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
            "value": "xx"
        },
        "height": {
            "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
            "value": "xx"
        }
    },
    "url": "http://www.yogabearpc.com/",
    "sameAs": ["https://www.facebook.com/yogabearpc",
    "http://www.twitter.com/YogaBearPC",
    "https://plus.google.com/+YogaBearPCRepairSacramento",
    "https://www.instagram.com/yogabearpc/",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/in/yoga-bear-computer-repair-178a32111",
    "https://www.pinterest.com/yogabearpc/",
    "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHmmLsYH9252HxlOjXD9t9w",
    "https://www.yelp.com/biz/yoga-bear-computer-repair-sacramento-2"]
}
</script>
```

You'll want to update specific values, such as the logo dimensions. These dimensions are Google-manadatory.

You also may wish to add time zone information on service hours (I didn't look-up that value for the `areaServed`).

Comment: Jay Gray that is amazing!!  Thank you!!

So for the AreaServed lat long by putting in coordinates it would make my service area a square or rectangle is that correct?  Any way to make a circle?

Thank you for taking the time.  I am so appreciative.

Also any further instructions on how to add a map would be super appreciated.  I didnt fully understand what you meant.  i would love to show a service area map

Comment: @MichaelGrippi I added `GeoCircle`. Adjust the `geoRadius` as appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelGrippi I also added the term to hold the URL for the map. Replace the comment with the real url. Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Jay Gray you are seriously incredible.
1)  is Georadius in meters?  So for 30 miles I would want roughly 50,000 as that figure?
2)  Is this the correct map url?   :     https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yoga+Bear+Computer+Repair/@38.5523201,-122.0039271,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x809ada9d2d5cc52f:0x3a1e4b41c5631552!8m2!3d38.552582!4d-121.443451

Comment: Thank you Jay Gray!

Comment: @MichaelGrippi Good map. The `geoRadius` is a bit sloppy (as your comment points out). There should be a unitOfMeasure associated with `geoRadius` to indicate whether the `number` is expressed in miles (Imperial) or meters (Metric). AFAICT the `number` is miles. My advice is align the number with the number used by Google Maps.

Comment: what is the proper code to add a unit of measure to the geo?  I am confused.  Everything I am reading online says default is meters but you clearly know more than I do

Comment: I do not know the default unit of measure. If your research says it's meters, then run with it. I'm gonna check with the schema.org folks because the documentation should be updated. BBTY when I learn an answer.